# Decipher Serial Port communication log of microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, reverse-engineering

I have an old robot (named qu-bot) that I had used in a school project. A few days ago, I began taking interest in Arduino. On closer inspection, I found that the old robot contains the ATMEGA16 chip. The robot came with a software that was used for programming it. It had a rather basic and limited programming language that is useless beyond school projects. But, it has quite a lot of sensors for me to practice on.

I was thinking of uploading Arduino's bootloader on it. A bit of research online revealed that repurposing old hardware often turns out to be a quite difficult task. Hence, the first step I tried was communicating with it on the serial terminal (UART) of Arduino IDE instead of terminal of the inbuilt software.

It turns out, as soon as Arduino's monitor tries to connect to Qu-Bot, it "locks down" itself. All functions stop and LEDs and sensors get turned off. When I reconnect it to inbuilt monitor, Qu-Bot gets "cured".

So, I thought of tapping into the communication going on in the COM port. I tapped into communication of Arduino IDE as well as inbuilt software. However, the report of the tap looks quite meaningless to me.
Can someone please help me decipher the report and tell what is causing the Qu-Bot to "lockdown"?

[Report of communication b/w Arduino IDE and bot](https://github.com/devmrfitz/qu-bot-data-dumps/blob/master/arduino_ide.csv)

[Report of communication b/w inbuilt software and bot](https://github.com/devmrfitz/qu-bot-data-dumps/blob/master/qu-bot_inbuilt.csv)

Comment: What did you use to "tap" into the communication? Some kind of USB sniffing software? If you don't have a serial bootloader flashed into the ATMEGA in the robot, you won't be able to use the Arduino software to program it, you'll have to flash the bootloader first.

Comment: @Ron Beyer There is a bootloader that comes inbuilt in the bot. I used "Eltima Serial Port Monitor" to tap

Comment: Does the robot communicate with its normal programming software over its serial port or in some other way? If it does use the serial port is that working correctly?

Comment: @Graham I can't answer all of these questions as I don't know the answer to many. These I know: I'm running Linux(Solus). Robot works normally if I don't try to connect arduino's monitor to it. If I try to, it locks down till the in-built software contacts it. It uses PL2303 programmer. UART Baud rate can be set using the same inbuilt software. Other questions in your comment are beyond my knowledge level.

Comment: @GrahamNye don't confuse the OP - a lot of those questions do not apply.

Comment: Analyzing the serial communication isn't really relevant to your goal.  If you want to install the Arduino bootloader, then the *only* way to do that is to use a programmer - you *cannot* do it through the serial port. Analyzing the existing serial communication would only be helpful if you want to re-use the existing software, for example maybe you think it has a serial bootloader of some sort that you might use instead of the Arduino one.  Note that you *cannot* install a bootloader *with* a bootloader due to hardware limitations of the ATmega family.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is what leads me to believe that bootloader can be installed using the USB port on the bot: There is another small software on the Qu-Bot CD named "Qu-Bot programmer" with only two buttons in it "Load hex/bin" & "Erase chip". When I erase chip and then try to program bot via the inbuilt IDE, it says, "There is no bootloader present on qu-bot. Proceed to load it? Do not disconnect bot until done". And then it takes thrice the usual time to load my code into qu-bot. Hence, it must be possible to reload a bootloader after "Erase chip"

Comment: Sorry, but you're misinterpeting the situation.  If you study the ATmega documentation, you will find that the bootloader cannot be replaced with a bootloader.  What you are seeing is a failure of communication.  The software is giving an alternate possibility that communication failed because there is no bootloader, when what has actually happened is that the bootloader momentarily isn't running, isn't in the right mode, or the serial coms are out of synch.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Is it possible to clean wipe the bootloader and then write the new one?

Comment: Only with an external programmer.  Depending on the current fusing of the chip an SPI-like ISP might work, otherwise you may need a more complex method at which point you're probably better off replacing the chip with a preprogrammed one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have a spare Arduino Uno. Is that any helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be to get a blank Atmega16 and an ISP cable.

Burn the Arduino bootloader to the new Atmega16 (instructions at various places on the internet.)

Pop the Atmega16 out of the Qu-Bot and plug in your new one.  Experiment to your heart's content.

This keeps the original Atmega available for comparison if you need it.  Besides, it may no be possible to overwrite the bootloader on the existing chip.

Comment: There are two reasons I'm avoiding this method: 1) The ATMEGA is strongly soldered on the bot. Removing it will most probably cause irreversible damage. 2) Even if I'm ready to take the risk of damaging the chip, the current Covid-19 lockdown means I can't go out to purchase a new ATMEGA16

Comment: Even in normal times there are very few places where on can purchase an ATmega16 in person (most that had *something* would have the 328p).  It's pretty much something you'd have to order.

Comment: The pictures of the [qu-bot](http://www.vegarobokit.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=110_117&product_id=571) I found all show the Atmega16 apparently in a socket.

Comment: @FitzWatson:  I did expect you'd have to order it.  I live in Germany, which is heavily populated.  It's still a 2 hour drive to the closest shop I know of that **might** have an Atmega16 in stock.  I order most things unless I need it **today.**

Comment: I actually meant that my country has stopped all non-essential services. Due to that, even online orders are out of question. Else, I'd have ordered the LEDs, sensors, etc instead of trying to reuse an old robot

Comment: @JRE Here are some closeups of the chip. Does it look removable? https://imgur.com/a/lQ49ZAq If yes, then I,ll unscrew the wheels and try pulling out the chip

Comment: That looks more like it's in a socket than that it's soldered in.

Comment: So, I just have to lift it out?

Comment: Use a small screwdriver.  Push it in under one end, and twist it.  Raise that end a little bit, then do the other end.  Back and forth, each end a little bit at a time until it comes out.  You need to be careful so as not to bend the pins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107437/discussion-between-fitz-watson-and-jre).

Comment: Successfully removed the chip. Now, if I follow "minimal configuration" part of this article, will I be able to program my Qu-bot(alongwith its sensors, etc) like my Uno?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the device schematics, the USB serial port chip DTR# output is directly connected to AVR reset pin. If the terminal program on PC opens up the serial port and sets DTR# pin low, it will keep the AVR in reset. Since the pin is active low, it means DTR is on. Terminal programs typically enable DTR, but it depends on handshake settings.

Comment: Basically, Qu-bot keeps infinitely resetting itself till the inbuilt software interferes?

Comment: No, it's not the qubot resetting itself infinitely, the PC serial terminal keeps the AVR reset. Until something on the PC commands the DTR line which lets the AVR run.

Comment: If the IDE keeps repeatedly saying "Reset yourself", then Qu-bot should stop resetting itself & work normally when I disconnect USB. But it doesn't normalise on disconnection or even powering the bot on and off. It normalises only when the inbuilt software communicates with it

Comment: You can't assume the output of PL2303 USB serial chip DTR# state unless a PC program has set the pin state. Get a terminal program where you can yourself control the DTR state.

Comment: A side question: Is the end result (using Qu-bot via Arduino IDE) possibly achievable or practically impossible without expertise in the field?

Comment: You would have to somehow burn the Arduino bootloader into it. Which will destroy the original bootloader, if it is read protected. So you may not be able to restore qubot software back. To do the Arduino bootloader programming you must at least connect the Mega16 temporarily to in-system programmer. However it may require removing the AVR from qubot board to program it. If in system serial programming is disabled, you must find a high voltage parallel programmer. If the AVR is socketed, it may be easier to replace the original chip with new one to preserve it. "Brain transplant" :)

Comment: If the Arduino IDE is able to work seamlessly with qubot, destroying qubot IDE isn't a concern at all. Does an Uno qualify as "in-system programmer"?